# Effective ways to implement Every-to-Every interaction?

Tags: python, c, algorithm, parallel-processing

Given a list of elements, how to process all elements if every element requires knowledge about states of every other element of this list?

For example, direct way to implement it in Python could be:

```
S = [1,2,3,4]
for e in S:
  for j in S:
    if e!=j:
      process_it(e,j)
```

but it is very slow O(n²)  if number of elements is huge. There must be another effective way, involving concurrency as well. Can you help me?

Comment: If your starting algorithm is O(n^2) and you can simplify it, then go for it. The implementation language concern is orthogonal to this.

Comment: As stated, there's no general way to make this much better. Now maybe the elements actually only need to know about *some* other elements or *summary information* calculated from all elements beforehand. It might be possible to go much faster. But the question doesn't provide enough information to even speculate about what the right trick might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to process every pair of items, there are O(n<sup>2</sup>) pairs, so you will have to make that many calls!

If you only need the combinations (ab, ac, bc), not all the permutations (ab,ba,ac,ca,bc,cb), then you can do this, to halve the number of calls (and skip the `if`):

```
for idA,val in enumerate(items):
    for idB in range(0, idA):
        process_it(val,items[idB])
```

The only way to improve it is to find a way of breaking down you `process_it` routine so it can work on multiple pairs. Without any more info, not much we can suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The suitability of a given task to be handled in multi-process fashion depends on the ***nature of the task*** and the interdependency (or lack thereof) of various subtasks, **not** on ***the way the list of subtasks is produced***.
In other words, using the question's wording, the ability for this problem to not be so ***slow*** by ***involving concurrency*** depends on the fact that the process_it() method is either such that:

- it produces the exact same outcome (direct and by side-effect) each time it is called with a given set of parameters.  (this is the typical case for a multi-processable task)
- its overall outcome for a series of calls is independent of the order of the series (this is a bit of a odd case of a multi-processable task).

And it doesn't depend on the fact that the order in which the series of calls to process_it() is produced by cartesian product of a list (the *Every-to-Every* of the question) or by some preconstructed list, or some other fashion.

Also, **the complexity of the problem** (O(n^2) in the question) **does not diminish because the problem is handed in a multi-process fashion**.  In fact the multi-process logic often introduces additional complexity (to "pay" for organizing and feeding the multiple threads and to combine their results); such added difficulty is however typically of an other order of magnitude of the problem (say constant, or maybe linear in n) and therefore doesn't change the overall complexity.

***Unrelated*** to the ability for the process to be split in multiple asynchronous subtasks, **it may be such that the complexity of the problem can be reduced**, as hinted in some other answers (for example if process_it(a,b) is the same as process_it(b,a), or if the underlying data is such that sorting it first could reduce the number of times process_it needs to be called etc.)

Also, and while some programming languages or libraries/environments make it easier to manage multi-processing, the question is generally language-agnostic; maybe the python tag and the illustrative snippet confuse the issue somehow.

Answer (score 0):

One sure option is to get it implemented in FPGA and have them all work concurrently. Other than that - if there are no exceptions and really -all- need -all-, not "some need some", you're sentenced to the standard approach.